# How to notify of object change in cloud store using gsutil without ApplicationUrl

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to notify my script running on linux of an object change in a bucket.

After reading the documentation I can notify an Application through url but this is not what I am looking for.

Is there any way I may listen for an object change through gsutil in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) is the recommended solution for getting notified of changes to a bucket. With the Cloud Pub/Sub integration, you can subscribe to changes from your script to the topic being published to.

If you want to receive the notifications from a command, you can use [gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull?hl=zh-TW).

Comment: hey sorry to bother you, but do you know if there is any command that does asynchronous pulling?